# Always see the title of a Chrome tab on Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have an app that displays *really* useful information in the tab title and I'd really love to be able to see this always. If I have too many tabs open or I pin it, the title shrinks and I can't read it any more. I am guessing a better place for it would be the Taskbar. Or put it in the empty space after the last tab. Or slam it in the URL bar. Or *whatever*. I am open to any good solution that makes it prominent. But I really need to see that title info. (WSL v2 is running, chocolatey is installed -- I am not afraid of the command line, should that be helpful.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Chrome is designed to shrink the tab names per the amount. It wouldn't make sense to have *every* title of a website on a big scroll wheel, especially because a lot of Chrome tabs can hurt your memory, and it wouldn't make sense to use them all at once to the point where the icons shrink.

My suggestion: Write a script that saves the title into a text file or a separate so you can at least see them.

Answer (score 0):

`Vertical tabs` is only solution for this problem.

**Edge** and **vivaldi** has built-in vertical tabs.
For chrome and brave, you need to install chrome extensions or write own chrome extension.

I try these 3 extensions. Find more at chrome web store:

1. **tabWindow**: Multi-window vertical tabs. chrome webstore link: [tabWindow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabwindow-multi-window-ve/lifdmcmbnbhaepoimjnohpnjhbpoljad)
2. **tabs Outliner**: Show tabs in tree style. chrome webstore link: [tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl)
3. **tabFlow**: Show tabgroups in tree style. chrome webstore link:[tabflow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabflow-tabgroups-in-tree/kmflkihdpehdjmdginjapjlgoldafjpc)